# JavaScript plugin options

Tags: javascript

A want to create a pure JavaScript plugin. Is it possible to set options in HTML file like if I set options for jQuery? If yes, how?

Example options in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myID").myFunction({
      folded: true,
      defaultSlide: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with _set options in HTML_ ?

Comment: And what is a *pure JavaScript plugin*?

Comment: The question is completely unclear. What does "plugin" mean? That word only has a useful meaning in context. What do you mean by "set options"? Your question raises more questions about itself than anything else.

Comment: At the end of the day, all you are doing is passing arguments to a function - this is not a jQuery specific thing - you can pass your options as arguments to the plugin function. You could even pass a single object holding many options.

Comment: The term "plugin" in JavaScript normally means "JavaScript that extends a library". The term "pure" usually means "without having a library". The terms seem mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the

```
{
  folded: true,
  defaultSlide: 1
}
```

in the quoted code, that has nothing to do with jQuery at all, it's just a JavaScript object initializer. Yes, your function can accept one and work with it:

```
function myFunction(options) {
    // use options.folded
    // use options.defaultSlide
}
```

The first part of your quoted code, the `$(...)`, is jQuery. To do something similar without jQuery, you'll obviously need to write that bit.

Here's an example that accepts options and sets the color of matching elements:

```js
function myFunction(selector, options) {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var color = options.color || "red";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].style.color = color;
  }
}

myFunction(".foo", {color: "blue"});
setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction(".bar", {color: "#008000"});
}, 300);
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="bar">bar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="bar">bar</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="bar">bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set extra attributes to the specified HTML element and just read them when you need:

```
<div id="myID" data-foo="bar"></div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myID'),
    foo = element.getAttribute('data-foo');
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. Check for example config for this pure JS plugin: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo_advanced.html

```
// create sound
ion.sound({
    sounds: [
        {name: "witchdoctor"}
    ],

    path: "static/sounds/",
    preload: true,
    multiplay: false
});
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Just a heads up, link only answers like these are not considered "good" answers as they are prone to link rot.

Comment: Sorry friends, it took some time to choose suitable code block. You are too quick.